# MySQL or JPQL query for getting different values from OneToMany relation (Condition priority)

Tags: mysql, if-statement, case, one-to-many, jpql

I have a table **products** which contains information like

| id | product_name | retailer_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Shirt | Gucci |

This table has a OneToMany connection with **product_prices** which contains information like

| id | price | country | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 95.5 | United Kingdom | 1 |
| 101 | 97.5 | France | 1 |
| 300 | 70.9 | EUROPEAN_UNION | 1 |

I need to create an MySQL or JPQL query which will retrieve

1. product_name
2. retailer_name
3. price (according to country or else choose European Union)

> So for example:  In case country United Kingdom is chosen -> then it
> will retrieve:
>
> 1. Shirt   Gucci  95.5
>
> In case country Italy is chosen -> then it will retrieve:
>
> 1. Shirt   Gucci  70.9
>
> As you can remark, in the second example, system retrieved
> EUROPEAN_UNION price because Italy could not be found.

> In case country EUROPEAN_UNION is chosen -> then it will retrieve:
>
> 1. Shirt   Gucci  70.9
>
> As you can remark, in the third example, system retrieved
> EUROPEAN_UNION price because EUROPEAN_UNION country was found.

How can I achieve that ?

I have in tried in JPQL something like :

```
select new com.ProductDTOWithPrice(p.id, p.product_name, p.retailer_name, " +
        "pr.price) " +
        "from Product p " +
        "join ProductPrice pr " +
        "where p.id =:productId and (case when pr.country=:country then 1 " +
        "else when pr.country.id = EUROPEAN_UNION then 1 end)"
```

Also, tried to make multiple selects or use exists, but still, I can not figure it out. I am getting stuck on retrieving ''price''.

```
    select p.id, p.name,
       Max(IF(pp.country_id = :countryId, true, false)) as mainCountry,
       Max(IF(pp.country_id = 400, true, false)) as europeanCountry
from products p
         join product_prices pp on p.id = pp.product_id
where p.id = '0002fb8977754949bf4da70535e1a2e6'
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Any help please ?

Comment: If someone gives you a jpql solution, and someone else gives you a MySQL solution, which one will you accept?

Comment: Any, it doesn't matter for me. I would prefer JPQL.

Comment: @Strawberry , can I know please, why did you remove my tags ? I said I need a solution  in mysql or jpql. And this question is related to one-to-many relation and to if-case-statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem using MYSQL :

```
SELECT p.id, 
       p.name, 
       pp.price, 
       country, 
       (CASE WHEN (pp.country_id = :country      ) THEN 3
             WHEN (pp.country_id = EUROPEAN_UNION) THEN 2                                        
             ELSE 0 END                                  ) AS priorityIndex
FROM       products p
INNER JOIN product_prices pp 
        ON p.id = pp.product_id
WHERE p.id  = '0002fb8977754949bf4da70535e1a2e6'
ORDER BY priorityIndex DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If anyone knows a better solution, please let me know.